# How to produce multiple media type using spring and jersey

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, jersey

I am new to REST.I have to come up with Rest Controller that will take file name as parameter and display its contents.Below is the code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/paths", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/pdf")

  public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> downloadPDFFile() throws IOException {

    ClassPathResource pdfFile = new ClassPathResource("PACKING LIST PDF 3000730933.pdf");

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
    headers.add("Pragma", "no-cache");
    headers.add("Expires", "0");

    return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).contentLength(pdfFile.contentLength())
        .body(new InputStreamResource(pdfFile.getInputStream()));
  }
```

Above code will display the contents of pdf since `produces = "application/pdf"` is mentioned. I want to have generic code that will take all file formats like `image`,`doc`,`docx`,`xls`,`xlsx` and display the contents and send the contents in Response.

Can anyone please suggest me the approach for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to achieve this to have separate mapping (method), which will produce specific format for you.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/paths")
public class YourApplication
{
      @RequestMapping(value = "/pdf", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/pdf")
      public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> downloadPDFFile() throws IOException {
         // you code for pdf
      }

      @RequestMapping(value = "/xlsx", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/xlsx")
      public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> downloadXLSXFile() throws IOException {
         // you code for xlsx
      }
}
```

Then, you can have following request url for specific type

```
/paths/pdf
```

and

```
/paths/xlsx
```